# How to disable auto reconnect in guacamole?

Tags: java, guacamole

I want to disable the auto reconnect in guacamole, auto connect has infinite number of attempts so want to disable it.

Any help with the configuration or code for extension of guacamole. Specifically if we get event for reconnect it will be helpful.